# How to remove a terminal character from a 'string' in C++ in O(1)?

Tags: c++

More formally, let `str` be the string in question, and let its length be `l`. I am aware that  the above can easily be accomplished using the `substr` function as follows:

- Removing the first character - `str.substr(1)`
- Removing the last character - `str.substr(0,l-1)`

But according to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) page, the above method does so in `O(l)`.

Is there a way to achieve the same in `O(1)`?

**Edit**: Before you mark this question as a duplicate, note that I am asking for an ***O(1)*** implementation for removing the terminal characters of a string. None of the answers to question of which this one is seemingly a duplicate of make any effort to answer this, apparently because *that* question doesn't ask for it.

Comment: It's always called O(n), you always use n.

Comment: AFAIK, `string::erase()` complexity isn't guaranted, but for last character it will work in `O(1)` in popular implementation. O(end - pos) in general

Comment: Destroying the original string? yes. But you probably need to work on the internals. A clever implementation will cache the size (pointing directly to the last char/terminator) and move the terminator one pos

Comment: `c++11` has [`pop_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/pop_back), but that only solves part of the problem.

Comment: Don't believe everything you read on cplusplus.com (or the Internet in general)!

Comment: Just be careful not to end up optimizing things that don't need to be optimized.

Comment: I'd try `str.resize(str.length()-1)`

Comment: @RiaD [This](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) page claims the complexity of `string::erase()` to be linear in the length of the new string, which makes doesn't make it any better than `substr`.

Comment: if you don't like to use n, use m or p or q.  why do you have to use l, which looks just like 1.

Comment: Please, avoid using lower case L in contexts where `1` is appropriate. It makes it unnecessarily hard to parse for humans

Comment: @Shubham That's a guaranteed worst case.  In general, `std::string::erase` will be `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of characters behind the area being erased.  So erasing at the end is cheap; erasing at the beginning is expensive.

Comment: Let's not neglect the constant factor.  `std::string::substr` has a relatively high constant factor, `std::string::erase` does its job in place, with an extremely low constant factor.  You can erase the first character of a string of perhaps a thousand characters more cheeply than to construct a substring of a single character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `substr` function doesn't remove characters. The string you call that function on does not get modified, so all characters remain intact. Nonetheless, the time required to call it to select a substring that includes all but a terminal character will be O(*n*) because it involves making a copy of all the other characters.

The time required for *removing* a character from a string lies in shifting all the subsequent characters to replace the one removed, much like the copying that occurs in `substr`. There are in general *n* characters in a string, so the complexity of removing an arbitrary character is O(*n*).

There is no constant-time way to remove the first character of a string of arbitrary length. Removing a character that's a fixed number of characters *C* from the *end* of a string can be done in constant time, so removing the final character (*C* = 0) is O(1).

If you frequently need to add or remove elements from the termini of a sequence, you might consider a data structure more suited to that operation. Both `list` and `deque` are good for that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of the standard actually guaranteeing this, but it is reasonable to *assume* that the complexity of:

```
str.resize(str.length() - 1);
```

is O(1). If an assumption isn't good enough for your case, you could write your own string class. Just make sure that the effort you'll spend in writing a good string class is worth the O(1) guarantee for removing the last character.

Comment: No, it is O(N). Source:- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon That's the worst case which happens when increasing the size.

Comment: @Nikos.C Can you share some source or proof of O(1) ?

Comment: My proof:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319712/why-is-stringresize-linear-in-complexity

Comment: @Guhfggehlthon `resize()` is implemented [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.1.0/libstdc++/api/a00293_source.html#l01091). When enlarging the string, it calls `append()`. When the new size if the same as the current one, it does nothing. However, when the new size is smaller, it just calls `erase()`. When calling `erase()` it doesn't change `capacity()` in this implementation of the standard library, which suggests that no new memory was allocated and thus nothing copied.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last character of a `std::string` in O(1) time,

you can just `resize` the string down 1 unit.

If you instead want an expression result (not modififying the original string) you will have to use some other class than `std::string`. A pair of iterators will do nicely.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see it was a duplicate (but now I expanded the comments list)