# Why is string::resize linear in complexity?

Tags: c++, string

The string needs to delete its old memory, then declare a new memory buffer, both of which are O(1) in complexity. The cplusplus.com reference says this is linear in time complexity of the *new string length*. Is this because the old string needs to be copied over? What if you start with an empty string?

Basically I want a string declared with a size n buffer, in O(1) time. Is this possible?

Comment: Might be a picky argument, but strictly speaking, even if allocation of `n` space would be possible, the memory could not be initialized (say with zeros) in constant time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every element of the new string is initialized, either by moving old elements, or by making copies of the second argument of `std::string::resize` (which defaults to `CharT()`).

Therefore the number of initializations is (new length).

One could imagine that for some future improved allocator that allowed in-place adjustment of a block size (like `realloc` from the C library), that the additional memory might be found contiguous to the old, and only max(0, (new length) - (old length)) initializations needed.  But the current allocator scheme doesn't support such.

Answer (score 2):

The string content also needs to be copied or initialized which, obviously, has a complexity linear in the new size of the string.

Comment: Sorry, i added an edit. The complexity is in terms of the new string length. So by that logic, if I started with an empty string (nothing to copy over), and resize to 100, then that would be the complexity of the resize?

Comment: @JoshMerle: OK. I had neglected to mention the initialization of characters. I added that to my answer.